# Testing directive that uses $document with angular-mocks

Tags: unit-testing, angularjs

I'm trying to test a directive that makes use of the angular $document element to attach an event handler to. However, when I run a test against it using Jasmine and angular mocks, I get an error when then linkfn of the directive executes.

Directive something like this:

```
angular.module('myDirective', []).directive('myDirective',
function () {
    function keydownHandler(ev) {
        alert('keydown');
    }
    return {
        template: '<input type="text" />',
        link: function ($scope, $document) {
            $document.on('keydown', keydownHandler);
        }
    }
});
```

Error:

```
TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'on'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This won't work because the link function doesn't support dependency injection. As stated in the documentation about [directives](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive), the link function accepts 4 parameters - scope, element, attributes and controller.

```
link: function(scope, element, attributes, controller) {
  // do the linking here
}
```

[Here](http://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-scope-vs-scope) is a video describing this in greater details.